# Xamarin, cant give style to a Button

Tags: c#, xamarin

I got the following code in my app:

```
    new Button {
       Margin = 0,
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
       Text = ">",
       BackgroundColor = Color.Lime,
       BorderWidth = 10,
       BorderColor = Color.Black,
       BorderRadius= 0,
 },
```

Some of this styles work correctly but somes, no. I put a picture of the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border properties are very unreliable on xamarin forms, the best way to achieve them is to write a custom renderer for you button.